# Article "the" with relative clauses

Tags: grammaticality, articles, all-the

I am not confident about my judgement as to whether or not "the" is required if a relative clause is used in a sentence.
For example,

> The data can be collected on all the computers on which the software is installed.

I think it must be "all the computers " and not be "all computers" because "computers" is specified  by  "on which the software is installed".

Please help me confirm that I am right.

Comment: I also think your sentence is right because of the reason you named: you are pointing to some computers with a specific software, not any computers in the sphere of the "world: computers". So the use of "the" in this sentence sounds right.

Comment: I think it's acceptable either way.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, user3158 and Barmar. Now I think that I have stuck in between grammer and sound. I thought it is grammatically ok with "the", and it sounds ok in either way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If you wanted to remove "the" it would be better to slightly reword the last half of the sentence:

> The data can be collected on all computers which have the software installed.

The key difference is the "on which":

> The data can be collected on all computers on which the software is installed.

A shorter example:

> Find computers on which the software is installed.

This doesn't feel so very wrong that I would call it completely ungrammatical but it definitely works better with "the":

> Find the computers on which the software is installed.

Comment: Mrhen, thank your for your detailed comments. I have never taken the way of thinking grammer as you mentioned above. When thinking "on which" as a key to the problem, it started to be clearer to me that I should put "the" or not. Very helpful,thank you again.

Comment: @Newdarkhourse at least you can vote up the answer you liked or mark it correct if it worked for you :)